# nanopore - where to retrieve information from the basecaller used

Tags: nanopore, assembly, long-reads, base-calling

Where can I find information about the basecaller used in a specific nanopore run (we have a Gridion machine)?

I know already that we have `Guppy v. 3.0.3`, which I found out by clicking on the `about` tab on the MinKNOW GUI).

I was wondering, though, if additional information about the basecaller is outputted in any of the files generated when the run is finished? I checked already the `final_summary.txt` and it does not contain such information. I also checked the head of the `fastq` files and no further details.

My ultimate goal for the moment is to run [medaka](https://github.com/nanoporetech/medaka) on a draft genome assembly. But for that I'd need to specify the `medaka model`. From `medaka_consensus -h` I see that the options available and defaults are:

```
-m  medaka model, (default: r941_min_high_g330).
        Available: r941_min_fast_g303, r941_min_high_g303, r941_min_high_g330, r941_prom_fast_g303, r941_prom_high_g303, r941_prom_high_g330, r10_min_high_g303, r10_min_high_g340, r941_prom_diploid_snp, r941_min_high_g340_rle.
        Alternatively a .hdf file from 'medaka train'.
```

Therefore I already know that my option should contain `min` and `g303` (format of the models available described [here](https://nanoporetech.github.io/medaka/installation.html)). But know I'd need to find out the `{pore}` and `{caller variant}`

Comment: Pore? Say, "R9.4.1"? This is the pore is the physical protein (mutant curlin G with helicase) on your chip that you used. It likely will be r941, unless you are trialing out the new R10 pores.

Comment: Yes I also believe the pore would be R9.4.1. Not sure about the `caller variant` now

Answer (score 2):

I basecall separately with guppy. In the output folder specified by `--save_path` or `-s` there are a whole bunch of .log files.

```
$ ls -l *.log | head
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom 5242714 Dec  3 11:04 guppy_basecaller_log-2019-12-02_22-02-36.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom 5242718 Dec  3 11:06 guppy_basecaller_log-2019-12-02_22-04-38.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom 5242730 Dec  3 11:08 guppy_basecaller_log-2019-12-02_22-06-41.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom 5242879 Dec  3 11:11 guppy_basecaller_log-2019-12-02_22-08-50.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom 5242811 Dec  3 11:13 guppy_basecaller_log-2019-12-02_22-11-06.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom 5242817 Dec  3 11:15 guppy_basecaller_log-2019-12-02_22-13-28.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom 5242880 Dec  3 11:18 guppy_basecaller_log-2019-12-02_22-15-47.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom 5242816 Dec  3 11:20 guppy_basecaller_log-2019-12-02_22-18-09.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom 5242777 Dec  3 11:22 guppy_basecaller_log-2019-12-02_22-20-30.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom 5242742 Dec  3 11:25 guppy_basecaller_log-2019-12-02_22-22-47.log
```

The information you need for `medaka` is at the top of the **first** log file (alphabetically, and by creation date).

```
$ head -n 13 guppy_basecaller_log-2019-12-02_22-02-36.log 
2019-12-02 22:02:36.255793 [guppy/message] ONT Guppy basecalling software version 3.4.1+ad4f8b9
config file:        /opt/ont/guppy/data/dna_r9.4.1_450bps_hac.cfg
model file:         /opt/ont/guppy/data/template_r9.4.1_450bps_hac.jsn
input path:         raw/minion
save path:          test_341/minion
chunk size:         1000
chunks per runner:  512
minimum qscore:     7
records per file:   4000
num basecallers:    1
gpu device:         cuda:0
kernel path:        
runners per device: 4
```

If you ran live basecalling and you don't have those log files you could also try a recursive grep from the output folder, e.g.

```
grep -nr "^model file" .
```